# Linearity of determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I am trying to prove the following property of the determinants:

$$\begin{vmatrix} a_1\newline a_2 \newline \vdots \newline a_k=a_k'+a_k'' \newline \vdots \newline a_n \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} a_1\newline a_2 \newline \vdots \newline a_k' \newline \vdots \newline a_n \end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix} a_1\newline a_2 \newline \vdots \newline a_k'' \newline \vdots \newline a_n \end{vmatrix}$$

What I've figured out so far.

We have $$a_{kj}=a_{kj}'+a_{kj}'', j=1,2,\dots,n,$$ so the LHS of the equality we're trying to show is equal to $$\sum (-1)^{[i_1,i_2,\dots,i_n]}a_{1i_1}\dots a_{ki_k}\dots a_{ni_n} \\ =\sum (-1)^{[i_1,i_2,\dots,i_n]}a_{1i_1}\dots (a_{ki_k}'+a_{ki_k}'')\dots a_{ni_n}$$ May someone show me in details how is this sum equal to the sum of the determinants we have in the RHS as it's not obvious for me?

I don't see how we can write the given sum as two sums. What does happen with the $(-1)^{[i_1,i_2,\dots,i_n]}$ terms?

May I also ask why do we call this property 'linearity of determinants in terms of their rows and colums'? How should I understand this?

Comment: You are very close! You can split up the sum to get to what you want. Remember that $\color{blue}{x(a+a')y = xay + xa'y}$, so $\sum x(a+a')y =  \sum \left( xay + xa'y  \right) =  \sum xay + \sum xa'y$.

Comment: Yes, I actually see that the LHS is $$\sum (-1)^{[i_1,i_2,\dots,i_n]}a_{1i_1}\dots (a_{ki_k}'+a_{ki_k}'')\dots a_{ni_n}=\sum (-1)^{[i_1,i_2,\dots,i_n]}\left(a_{1i_1}\dots a_{ki_k}'\dots a_{ni_n}+a_{1i_1}\dots a_{ki_k}''\dots a_{ni_n}\right)$$ But how do I split it up as I also have $(-1)^{[i_1,i_2,\dots,i_n]}$?